# What Postgres privileges should I give to Flyway?

Tags: postgresql, flyway

I created a new database in Postgres and a new user dedicated specifically for schema migrations by Flyway.

```
createdb mydb
createuser mydb_deploy
```

What reasonable permissions should I give to this user, just sufficient for Flyway to connect to database and do schema migrations?

I'm new to Postgres and Flyway.

Comment: I would not create a database through Flyway. That is a DBA task that should be done by the DBA, not the application user.

Comment: I'm not planning to create a new database via Flyway. I just new to Postgres and confused what privileges the deployment user shouls have?

Comment: So why did you show the code to create a database and a user as an example? If you don't need to create a database from flyway, then just make the user the owner of that database, and no additional privileges are needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flyway user needs very high privileges because that will be the owner of all created objects.

You could simply deal out superuser privileges, but that should be avoided whenever possible.

When starting with an empty database, `GRANT ALL ON DATABASE` to the Flyway user so that it can create schemas in the database and then objects in the schemas.

Then the Flyway user will own all objects in the database, and everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I granted `GRANT ALL ON DATABASE mydb TO mydb_deploy;` and it worked.

Comment: How does this fit with the principle of least privilege? If the Flyway user has the superuser role, does it have more privileges that it really absolutely needs?

Comment: @Rubio You should definitely **never** use a superuser. I said "You could, ... but ...". However, tools that create their own tables do not play well with the principle of least privilege at all.

Comment: @Laurenz Agreed. I have to plan security hardening for our PostgreSQL database and this is a bit of a problem.